# TFS 2015 Build: An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop location. Details: Not found

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

**Tfs 2015 Build Partially succeeds or Build Fails.**

- If I change the setting to do no copy outputs to a drop folder , **the
  build fails with same error**( Strange isn't it, I configure it as don't copy it still copies (the diagnostic logs are copied always :) ) )
- If I change the setting to copy outputs to a drop folder and give a valid folder it **Partially succeeds**

> This happens to me in new TFS 2015 , Separate TFS Server, Separate SQL
>   server and Separate Build Server

.

The strange part is

1. The Build logs are copied successfully to the drop folder.
2. The build service is running using a domain account with R/W permissions to
   the Drop folder. So no issues in that front
   Changed the Drop Share to a different folder , no change
   Changed the Build service account to local account , no change
   Fighting for 4-5 days , no progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is quite amusing.
Enabled diagnostic logs for the build service, config file.
Then while analyzing the diagnostic logs, saw that Team build was pushing a Http PUT request to the TFS server, with the Log file details.
Interesting isn't it.
The error could have been more cleare

> The IIS Server was hosted in Windows 2012 SP2

.
**IIS 8** has a setting for > **Team foundation services** website, under

> Request Filtering -> Http Verbs

.

**Only Get , POST Verbs were allowed by default in my server**.

> Added PUT verb and set it to allow

-> there you go , Team Build starts working successfully.